# How to unit test a method with invalid parameters?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to test if i pass invalid parameters to my function it throws an excepction or something.

my function to test would be for example:

```
       public int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b){
         return a+b;
       }
```

so in junit if i call the function like:

```
      Number number = new Numbers();
      int result = number.addTwoNumber("string", 3);
```

it will throw an exception because of the "string" parameter.

How could i unit test this function?

Comment: it's going to be a compile-time error for you.

Comment: It won’t throw an exception as it won’t compile.

Comment: You can't. Firstly, unit test case must be compiled :)

Comment: Thanks, that is my question.

Comment: I know it won'nt compile, that's why i asked my question. If you cannot answer the question don't downvote and off the topic, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in trying to test it for this.

The compiler already checks if you pass in the wrong argument types: it won't let you compile such code, so there is no risk of you running it and the code failing because of receiving parameters of the wrong type.

And even if you try to invoke the method reflectively with the wrong parameter types, it will fail at runtime.

Suffice to say, this is just not something you need to care about in your tests. If you don't believe that the compiler can do this correctly, you basically have to worry that it could get anything else wrong too, and have test that too.